# Which of the following powers is bigger: $2^{41}$ or $3^{24}$?

Tags: arithmetic, exponential-function

Calculate the maximum between the given numbers
 $$ \max(2^{41},3^{24})\text{.}$$ 
I got stuck when I tried to decompose the exponent as $41$ is a prime number.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

$$2^{41}\gt 2^{40}=(2^5)^8\gt (3^3)^8=3^{24}$$

Comment: Should I know 2^5 is bigger than 3^3 without calculating that 2^5=32 and 3^3=27?

Comment: @Dean MacGregor, no, except that many people know those small powers by rote (e.g., binary sequence in computer science and perfect cubes to reduce cube roots).

Answer (score 13):

Recall that $2^{10} = 1024 > 1000 = 10^3$ (well-known from computer science as the size of a kilobyte), and $3^2 = 9 < 10$, so that
$$
2^{41} > 2^{40} = (2^{10})^4 > (10^3)^4 = 10^{12} > (3^2)^{12} = 3^{24}.
$$

Answer (score 7):

It suffices to see $2^{20}>3^{12}\iff 2^{10}>3^6\iff 2^{5}>3^3$

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively $$2^{41} > 2^{40} = (2^8)^5 > (3^5)^5 = 3^{25}$$ shows an even stronger statement.

Answer (score 2):

A definitive answer using log functions:

log(3) / log(2) = 1.58496

3<sup>24</sup> = (2<sup>1.58496</sup>)<sup>24</sup> = 2<sup>1.58496 * 24</sup> = 2<sup>38.039</sup>

Therefore: 2<sup>41</sup> > 3<sup>24</sup>

Comment: instead of calculating $log 3 / log 2$, you can simply calc $log_2 3$ ... binary log is quite common IMO, no need to go for natural one here.

Answer (score 1):

$$ 2^{41} = 2,199,023,255,552 > 282,429,536,481 = 3^{24} $$

### Edit

Apparently this answer isn't 'mathematical' enough for some commenters as it is direct, simple, and verifiable, but doesn't use log functions and all that other Algebra II knowledge we are so proud of. Anyone in the world should be able to make the above calculation to more than the required degree of accuracy, as follows:

$$ 2^{41} = 2 * (2^{10})^4 = 2 * (1024)^4 \underset{\approx}{>} 2 * (1000)^4 = 2,000,000,000,000 $$
and 
$$ 3^{24} = (3^2)^{12} = 9^{12} \underset{\approx}{<} 10^{12} = 1,000,000,000,000 $$

### Edit 2

@AriBrodsky uses exactly the above calculation in an answer that was posted after mine but before my edit. I didn't see it until now. It is clearly the best answer, but I leave my edit for clarity.

Comment: you made a mistake when calculating $2^{41}$

Comment: @dREaM 2199023255552?

Comment: yup${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @jwg IMO the obvious implication of the "Calculate (...)" question was "find a way to get the result of $max$ without doing the actual numerical evaluation"

Comment: @vaxquis We don't agree about the 'obvious' meaning of the word 'Calculate' then.

Comment: you assume that OP is too stupid to use a calculator? Pity. There are numerical calculations, and there are symbolic calculations; since this task is completely trivial numerically and somewhat non-trivial symbolically, assuming that a numerical solution is OK is absurd. Also, the question wouldn't have been on-topic on math.SE if it should've been answered the way you did, as per http://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic . Also, going along your lines, *calculus* should be about arithmetics.

Comment: @vaxquis Making a trivial problem non-trivial by solving it in a convoluted way isn't mathematics.

Comment: OP provided a classical textbook example of a task requiring only basic math *knowledge* as a prerequisite, instead of *computations*. If you're saying that comparing $41$ with $log_2 3 * 24$ is a "convoluted" and "non-trivial" operation, while you consider numerically evaluating $2^{41}$ and $3^{24}$ a "trivial" one, I honestly have nothing more to add; I wish you the best of luck with applying your "trivial" methods to e.g. RSA computations; I also honestly hope you'll live long enough to be able to actually *trivially compute* the $c^d$, instead of using "non-trivial" discrete relations.

Comment: @vaxquis How did you work out $\log^{2}3$? Did you use a calculator?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31065/discussion-between-vaxquis-and-jwg).